# Filter and delete Registry values with Where-Object

Tags: powershell, registry

I'm not sure why I'm finding this so difficult. From under a particular registry key, I'd like to query certain registry-values based on their data (not name), and delete the resulting registry-values.

**For example:**

[image: screenshot of registry]

How would I delete any values in this key that contain, let's say, "foo". I can list the registry values with `Get-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\RestoreOnStartupURLs'`, but it intermingles some rubbish along with the actual data:

```
1            : http://foo.example.com
2            : http://bar.example.com
PSPath       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\RestoreOnStartupURLs
PSParentPath : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome
PSChildName  : RestoreOnStartupURLs
PSDrive      : HKCU
PSProvider   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```

I was trying to pipe to `Where-Object` but can't find a query that works. And then I'd need a `Remove-` cmdlet that can handle the result. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this issue is a matter of stepping back and taking a look at the bigger picture. You're focused on the value or a property, and how to get that property name that you aren't taking into consideration that the property is just a part of a larger object, the key. Let's work with the key's object and see where that gets us. I'm going to assign the path to a variable, because we'll use it later.

```psh
$KeyPath = 'HKCU:\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\RestoreOnStartupURLs'
$ChromeKey = Get-Item $KeyPath
```

Now that object is `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey` object with some helpful methods built in to it. The one that we are concerned with for your needs is called `GetValueNames()`, which (unsurprisingly) gives you the names of the values, which for you should return:

```psh
(default)
1
2
```

So, we pipe that into a `Where` statement that gets the actual values for those names, matches them for Foo, and then we act upon them. First things first, getting those properties that we are concerned with:

```psh
$ChromeKey.GetValueNames() | Where {$ChromeKey.GetValue($_) -match "foo"}
```

That command should return one value, `1`. Then just use that as needed with something like Remove-ItemProperty...

```psh
$ChromeKey.GetValueNames() | Where {$ChromeKey.GetValue($_) -match "foo"} | ForEach{ Remove-ItemProperty -Path $KeyPath -Name $_ }
```

Done, that will find all values of your key that match 'foo' and remove them from the key.